# What did Lord Carnarvon study at Trinity College Cambridge?

Tags: ancient-egypt

This question is about the famous Egyptologist. I read that [he was educated at Eton and Trinity College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Herbert,_5th_Earl_of_Carnarvon), but cannot find information about his time at Cambridge - in particular what degree he obtained.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Brian Fagan's ***Lord and Pharaoh: Carnarvon and the Search for Tutankhamun***, p. 55, he was "sent down for academic reasons after a year." So he did not obtain any kind of degree. The book doesn't indicate what he studied.

This seems consistent with his earlier studies at Eton, which were quite unsuccessful; Fagan speculates that he may have had some kind of learning disability.

Comment: It's quite hilarious that Trinity College [lists him among its notable alumni](https://www.trin.cam.ac.uk/alumni/famous-trinity-alumni/notable-alumni/) regardless.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy  An _alumnus_ of a university is merely a former student, not necessarily a graduate, and Carnarvon was certainly a notable one.

Comment: For those not au fait with Oxbridge terminology: sent down = expelled (whilst rusticated = suspended).

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Not disagreeing on the vocabulary. What struck me as disingenuous of theirs is that they were piggybacking on his name in spite of the fact that they kicked him out after a year -- i.e. in reality they arguably had nothing to do with that alumni's later success in life. (Granted, he was privileged so would have succeeded regardless. But still.)

Comment: It's the sign of a University that can own up to its mistakes. They do it quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Does the book tell what he attempted to study?

Comment: @jl6 Unfortunately not.